# Can't load assets on subpage. Laravel app

Tags: php, view, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('asdf/zxcv', function()
{
    $posts = Auth::user()->posts()->get();

    return View::make('posts', compact('posts'));
});
```

The view extends a master layout, where the CSS and Javascript files are loaded. The content (in this case, posts) loads perfectly and I see the `<link>` tags in the `<head>` when the page loads, but no styles are being applied.

Comment: Alas there's nothing in your question to give any clue as to what's causing the problem. The code you've supplied is close to boilerplate and should work fine. The problem is going to be related to the views and their relationship to each other and the assets, rather than how you supply post data to them.

Comment: Right now what I'm doing is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.min.css') }}">`. It works, it translates to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.com/css/style.min.css">` but I'd prefer a relative path. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is relative. Laravel converts your relative address into an absolute link, but does so in the context your current domain. If you move to a new domain, Laravel will use that instead, so although expressed absolutely, the link remains relative to the current domain.